# How to change BeautifulSoup's parser?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I was wondering how you would achieve this.

In the documentation it mentioned to do:

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
```

I tried that where the markup is the html file I'm reading and all I got was this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`
```

Comment: Are you confusing the `BeautifulSoup` module (version 3) and the `bs4` module (version 4)?

Comment: I think I might be, I'm using version 3, is there any way to change the parser in that?

Comment: Look at the old BeautifulSoup documentation.

Comment: Here is the old documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

Comment: No, BeautifulSoup 3 uses its own parser, and as far as I know, you can't change that. BeautifulSoup 4 can change parsers.

Comment: Even I faced this same issue. But once I removed `"lxml"`, the code worked fine. I was even able to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I can definitively state that Beautiful Soup 3 does not allow a choice of parsers. You'll need to use Beautiful Soup 4.